# Mocking fetch: Jest test says response is wrong, but actually running the code works as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, fetch

I have an async event, `createEvent`, which contains fetch, meant to save data to a DB, and returns `true` on success and `false` on fail and `null` on error. It is actually doing so properly, as demonstrated by running this code:

```
let result = await createEvent(newEvent);
console.log("Result:", result);
if (result) {
  setMessage("Event added!");
} else {
  setMessage("Error adding event, please try again later");
}
```

In this case, the console logs `true` and the message is set correctly.

However, when I run the following test, it fails:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => 
    Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({ success: true }),
    })
);

it('returns proper value', () => {
    expect(createEvent(newEvent)).toBe(true);
});
```

This is the relevant output from Jest:

```
console.log src/components/EventForm.js:60
    Fetch response: { json: [Function: json] }

  console.log src/components/EventForm.js:66
    resJson: { success: true }
.
.
.
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: {}
```

I'm not sure why Jest would be getting different results. I'm new to Jest and testing in general, so open to any other corrections as well. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to mark your test `async` and `await` the execution of the `createEvent()` call before your expectation:

```
it('returns proper value', async () => {
  const result = await createEvent(newEvent);
  expect(result.success).toBe(true);
});
```

[image: Edit goofy-hamilton-mho0q] (go to Tests tab on the right)

Alternately, if you don't want to deal with the manual mocking of `fetch`, you can checkout [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock).

Comment: Thank you, so simple! I ended up using jest-fetch-mock which works great, I just wanted to also understand what's going on behind the scenes.